# Assembly: 16-bit Division

Tags: assembly, x86, division

I'm still new to assembly and I don't know many command codes in assembly yet. I want to do a division in a 16-bit register. I want to print its content. I know that I need to convert the content of the register into ASCII for printing but again, my problem is the division. Please help me.

For example, the content of cx is 2012 (integer). What should I do?

```
 mov ax, cx
 mov bx, 1000
 idiv bx
```

The above code is wrong, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** I noticed that this is signed division `idiv`, answer edited accordingly.

The above code is wrong in one aspect: `ax` is not sign-extended to `dx:ax`.

Just add `cwd` (convert word to doubleword) before `idiv bx`, and then it's correct. The quotient will be in `ax` and the remainder will be in `dx`.

Comment: Thanks. BTW, in printing of characters here, it is possible to use mov dx, <character> instead of mov dl, <character> since I'm dealing with 16-bits right?

Comment: If you zero `dh`, then yes. So `mov dx,'a'` and `mov dh,0; mov dl,'a'` produce identical register values and neither changes flags.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [this reference](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html) (search for idiv)

> The idiv instruction divides the contents of the 64 bit integer
>   EDX:EAX (constructed by viewing EDX as the most significant four bytes
>   and EAX as the least significant four bytes) by the specified operand
>   value. The quotient result of the division is stored into EAX, while
>   the remainder is placed in EDX. Syntax idiv  idiv
>
> Examples
>
> idiv ebx — divide the contents of EDX:EAX by the contents of EBX.
>   Place the quotient in EAX and the remainder in EDX. idiv DWORD PTR
>   [var] — divide the contents of EDX:EAS by the 32-bit value stored at
>   memory location var. Place the quotient in EAX and the remainder in
>   EDX.

Of course, since you're using 16-bit, cut all of the specified bit-values in half and drop the E off of each register and it's the exact same

Comment: So, for the OP requirement, he/she just needs to zero EDX/DX?

Comment: @MartinJames yes, if they're just dividing a 16-bit number by a 16-bit number.

Comment: Since we're using "idiv" instead of "div", "cwd" (sign extend ax into dx) might be better...

Comment: @FrankKotler yea, since otherwise it wouldn't work right with negatives

Comment: @FrankKotler `cdq` extends `eax` to `edx:eax`. To extend `ax` to `dx:ax`, `cwd` is should be used.